# Merging two JSON objects with PHP?

Tags: php, json

I have two JSON objects, and I want it to be merged into one JSON object. I don't want the JSON data to be **overwritten**. I want the data to be **merged**.

**Object #1: (example1.json)**

```
[{
    "title": "xx",        
    "releaseYear": "2014",        
},
{
    "title": "yy",       
    "releaseYear": "2015"        
}]
```

**Object #2: (example2.json)**

```
[{
    "title": "yy",       
    "releaseYear": "2017"

}]
```

This is the **PHP File** I currently am using:

```
    <?php

    $jsonString = file_get_contents('example.json');
    $jsonString2 = file_get_contents('example2.json');   
    $data = json_decode($jsonString, true);
    $data2 = json_decode($jsonString2, true);      


    $op = array_merge_recursive( $data, $data2 );

    $resJson = json_encode($op);
    file_put_contents('example3.json', $resJson);
```

**Output received: (example3.json)**

```
[  
   {  
      "title":"xx",
      "releaseYear":"2014"
   },
   {  
      "title":"yy",
      "releaseYear":"2015"
   },
   {  
      "title":"yy",
      "releaseYear":"2017"
   }
]
```

**Required Output:**

```
[{
    "title": "xx",        
    "releaseYear": "2014"        
},
{
    "title": "yy",       
    "releaseYear": "2017"        
}]
```

Solutions appreciated. Am new to Stackoverflow, so sorry for my bad formatting, if any. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Release year doesn't match on given objects. Is this correct? If so, does this mean you always have to take higher release year value on matching titles when doing merge?

Comment: I'm confused, you don't want to overwrite data, you want to merge, but the result you're asking for is clearly overwriting, not just merging ?

Comment: Overwritten:
[{
    "title": "yy",       
    "releaseYear": "2017"        
}]

Since there is only one object, it overwrites, and merges the second data alone. This is what I meant as overwriting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many possible solutions. One example:

```
<?php
$data = json_decode('[{"title": "xx","releaseYear": "2014"},{"title": "yy","releaseYear": "2015"}]', true);
$data2 = json_decode('[{"title": "yy","releaseYear": "2017"}]', true);

$data = foo($data, 'title');
$data = foo($data2, 'title', $data);
$data = array_values($data);
var_export($data);

function foo($src, $prop, $target=array()) {
    foreach($src as $o) {
        $target[ $o[$prop] ] = $o;
    }
    return $target;
}
```

Comment: First of all, thanks for your answer. Well, I ran it, and it gave me this output:
array ( 0 => array ( 'title' => 'xx', 'releaseYear' => '2014', ), 1 => array ( 'title' => 'yy', 'releaseYear' => '2017', ), )

That's what I need. But can I get it in JSON format? Like:
[{
    "title": "xx",        
    "releaseYear": "2014"        
},
{
    "title": "yy",       
    "releaseYear": "2017"        
}]

Later, this data will be parsed in Android with Volley, it doesn't recognize that type of data, that's why. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Thanks for the solution @VolkerK. A simple google helped me to get it in JSON format. 
Used echo json_encode($data); instead of var_export($data);
Thanks again, if you're free, do tell me the use of using var_export :)

Comment: I just like the output better than that of var_dump ;-) You can copy the output of var_export and paste it (as-is) back into a php script to use it as sample data.